# Mouse jumping issue in VMWare Workstation's linux guest

Tags: vmware-workstation, rhel-6, oracle-linux

1. Oracle linux 6 is installed with XFCE 4 desktop on VMWW 14
2. VMWare tools have been installed
3. During mouse moving the Cursor is jumping to borders of the screen - it does not move smoothly.

How it could be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing vmmouse driver fixed it for me (available through epel repository):

```
# rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

# yum install xorg-x11-drv-vmmouse
```

After rebooting, the mouse moved smoothly for me.

Comment: Just to confirm, did this specific fix work for you?  It's OK to say "Installing vmmouse driver fixed it for me" and "After rebooting, the mouse moved smoothly for me".  That would be an excellent answer for someone to find in the future.